"What color are your hairs?”
I have a question about this sentence and I wonder whether it's correct or not.

What color are your hairs?

Is this sentence grammatical?

It's not the grammar that is wrong, but the fact that hair is an uncountable noun when it refers to all the hair on a person's head. We only speak of 'hairs' when we mean individual strands of it. So you should ask

What colour is your hair?

